# How to "Move Caret Forward a Statement" when editing python code in PyCharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I can find "Move Caret Forward a Paragraph" but it only goes down to the next empty line. Example of what I want to achieve:

```
var1 = 'statement1'
var2 = [
    'statement2a',
    'statement2b',
    'statement2c',
    'statement2d',
]
var3 = 'statement3'
var4 = 'statement4'
```

Here I'd like the caret to jump from `var2` to `var3`. We often have long SQL statements I'd like to skip instead of hitting down array 50 times. This is inspired by the book Pragmatic Programmer which suggests trying to work without a mouse to be able to work your code base faster.

PyCharm knows what a "statement" in python is because there exists a "Move Statement Up/Down" operation which moves a statement (like the `var2` assignment).

Solutions I've been considering:

- Search more for it in the documentation.
- Make a feature request.
- Search for a plugin which does it. Like Extra Actions.
- Create a macro. Although they seem to be slow.
- Write my own plugin.
- Asking here.

Comment: Not exactly .. but AceJump kind of plugin and jump anywhere on the page? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7086-acejump

Comment: That looks really neat. I'm trying it out.

Comment: The actual request / ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166995

Answer (score 0):

Try Main Menu | Navigate | Navigate in File | **Next/Previous Method** action.

Comment: As I understood OP wants something like this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166995

Comment: @LazyOne Indeed. I use Next Method all the time. You move to ... well the next method/function when you use it. I want to move to the next statement. Thanks for the link btw.